# Render normals in camera space

Tags: rendering, normals

After many hours of searching, trying and scratching my head I turn to you guys. Seems like many other have this same problem but haven't seen any solution to this yet.

I am rendering cars in blender and I do most of my post work in Photoshop. To do this I need a "correct" render of the normals and I just can't achieve this in Blender.

This is a ref image of what I am looking for and this Normal render is from 3Ds or Cinema 4D (I think).

I use this Normal to color range select parts of the car facing a certain way.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This can be done with the workbench engine, if you *don't* need motion blur as shown in your example image and the colors *don't* have to be 100% accurate. For accurate results you will have to create a material for Cycles and Eevee.

---

### Approach 1: Workbench Engine

[image: Example render]

1. Switch to the *Workbench* engine

[image: Workbench engine]

2. Enable *MatCap* as material and select the normal map matcap.

[image: MatCap]

3. Enable *Transparent* for the *Film*

[image]

4. Set the *View Transform* to *Standard*

[image: Set the view transform]

---

### Approach 2: Material for Cycles and Eevee

[image: Render]

If you need accurate results, then you have to create a material for Cycles and Eevee that transforms the object's normals into camera space and uses them as a color for the object. This can be accomplished by transforming the *Normal* output of the *Geometry* node, which gives the normal in world space, into camera space with the *Vector Transform* node. In order to get the proper colors you will have to adjust the output though, since the camera normals have the following ranges:

$$ x: [-1.0, 1.0]\\ y: [-1.0, 1.0]\\z:[-1.0,0.0]$$

Colors have to be in a  $[0.0,1.0]$ range, therefore the vector has to be multiplied with $[0.5, 0.5, -0.5]$ componentwise and then shifted by $[0.5, 0.5, 0.5]$. The node setup is depicted in the following image. Note that the emission shader is only visible from the camera and therefore doesn't impact other objects in the scene.

[image: Node setup]

Make sure to either save the result as OpenEXR or set the *View Transform* to *Raw* to get the exact pixel values.

---

The result produced with the second approach is more accurate, since it calculates the normals properly instead of performing a look up in the matcap bitmap. The material doesn't have to be assigned to every object individually if you use [*material override*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/layers/layers.html#override) as [@RobinBetts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/35559/robin-betts) mentioned.

[image: Material override]

Comment: Your edit read my mind. BTW, do you know? Is the 'Normal' setting of the Vector Transform node just the normalized 'Vector' setting? it's not very well documented .. BTW BTW.. I suppose you could make a pass with a material override ..

Comment: Yes the *Normal* option normalizes the value. It's not needed here since the input is already normalized.

Comment: THANKS @rjg
This is exactly what I was going for! The material setup work awesome.
I was afraid I would get banding when selecting colors but I didn't.

Thanks again!

Comment: @gubbfet Great! If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Do you mean the part where you reverse the mapping from [0, 1] back to [-1, 1] in order to retrieve the normal vector as shown [here](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-Lighting/Normal-Mapping)?

Comment: With the exception of floating point errors, the output should already be normalized. If you want to be 100% sure, then add a *Vector Math* with the operation set to *Normalize* after the *Combine* node. I think the normalization for OpenGL should always be necessary when using a format like PNG that can only store values in the [0, 255] range (no floating point values like e.g OpenEXR).

Comment: @Tenfour04 The components of the original normal vector cannot be accurately represented by the image due to the mapping from [0, 1] floating point to [0, 255] integer. The values have to be multiplied by 255, but the fractional part cannot be represented and has to either be rounded up / down or clamped. Thus trying to get the original vector components back from the image will result in a vector that is longer or shorter and not normalized.

Comment: Sorry, my original question was based on your Approach 1, which doesn't produce accurate normals that are usable for what I'm doing anyway. That was my original issue. I'll delete that comment. I'm now using Approach 2. Also want to point out that to do a material override, you need to use Cycles rather than Eevee. I was stuck for a while on that.

Comment: Can Screen Space Normal Pass include bump that exists in shaders applied to objects? The approaches listed are considering only geometric normals, so they disregard shaders.

Comment: @VladimirLoginov No they do not, MatCaps replace the existing shader. You could probably incorporate normal maps into the shader based approach though.