# How to create render of normals?

Tags: normals

When looking at object at solid view using MatCap normal map light, I get a nice normal map of object I am looking at.

[image: Nice normal map of monkey.]

However, when I try to recreate those colors for rendering, using Geometry Node -> True Normal, I get something very different.

[image: Ugly normal map of monkey.]

Can anyone explain, what is going on, or even better, how to change the node setup so I get image as in solid view?
Thank you!
Adam

Comment: Hello and welcome. you should add your Geometry nodes tree as part of your question, to give an idea of what you've done so far, the more info of your settings, the better

Comment: Do you have to do it in geometry nodes? You can just use workbench render and chose a matcap or use the node setup stated here -> https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/157279/115533

Comment: These are both the (remapped) normal, but in different spaces.  The matcap is the (Z flipped) camera-space normal; the GN true normal is the object-space normal.  If you want to render a matcap, you can render it with a "viewport render image" operation.  You can also search SE for how to make a matcap material to render a regular render.

Comment: @Nathan you can use workbench engine to render a matcap.